# Is this photo of a LGBT protest march digitally faked?

Tags: photography, media

I saw this in a Spanish [forum](http://m.forocoches.com/foro/showthread.php?t=5062122), which isn't exactly the most reliable source..

[image]

Was this picture of a LGBT protest march digitally faked?

Comment: I still would like to know *what* you think is digitally faked? The text? The *entire* text, or just the top 3 no/no/yes lines that seem to be skewed?

Comment: I see no notable claim that the photo is fake.  Voted to close.

Answer (score 24):

This image shows the banner of a group called LGBT Against Islamophobia. The specific image was taken at [Birmingham Pride in 2015](https://lgbtai.wordpress.com/2015/05/26/lgbt-against-islamophobia-at-birmingham-pride/), but they were also at other prides such as London Pride.

<sub>Personally, I agree that it may seem a bit odd to focus on religious discrimination or racism at pride, but I see no irony in one oppressed group being against the discrimination of a different oppressed group.</sub>

<sub>It seems that an implied question here is if islam is especially homophobic - for example compared to christianity. One source to answer this would be the [Pew Research Center](http://www.pewforum.org/2015/11/03/chapter-4-social-and-political-attitudes/). In 2014, 45% of muslims said that homosexuality should be accepted by society, compared to 62% overall, 71% Hindu, 54% Christian, 36% Evangelical, 81% Jewish, 88% Buddhist or 94% atheists.</sub>

Comment: I don't see the point of your last 2 paragraphs. Answers on skeptics shouldn't contain *opinions*, and I don't get why you ask & self answer a different question in your last paragraph.

Comment: @Bakuriu the question was edited after I answered. Originally, OP said that they would find the image ironic if it were authentic, implying that muslims may be more homophobic than other groups. This also seemed to be one of the reasons OP doubted the authenticity of the image, so I thought that providing some inside into that may help.

Comment: Yes, and that portion was correctly edited out, so I don't see the point of keeping your discussion on that in the answer. Either edit the question to include such point, or just remove it.

Answer (score 16):

Unlikely, there are many sites showing photographs of the same banner being held by different people.

Here is a screenshot of search results to exemplify:

[image]

These pictures come from widely dissimilar websites like

- [LGBT against islamophobia](https://lgbtai.wordpress.com/2015/06/29/lgbtai-at-london-pride/)
- [Alamy stock photo](http://www.alamy.com/stock-photo-dover-uk-02nd-apr-2016-a-banner-is-held-which-reads-lgbt-against-islamophobia-101664255.html)
- [Stormfront.org](https://www.stormfront.org/forum/t1149364-4/)
- [Unite against fascism](http://uaf.org.uk/2016/07/lgbt-solidarity-with-victims-of-orlando/)
- [Socialist worker](https://socialistworker.co.uk/art/42943/LGBT%2B+Against+Islamophobia+meets)
- [AllEvents meeting planner](http://allevents.in/london/lgbt-against-islamophobia-planning-meeting-and-iftar/208159642915961#)

... to name a few.